# Connecting to SQL Server from EXE file on shared drive

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment, .net-3.5

Our software uses a `SqlConnection` object to get data from SQL Server. It is running fine for many sites, but for one specific user - it cannot connect to the server. I get an exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.

On this PC the executable file is located on a shared drive. If we copy the executable to a local drive (the desktop) and run it from there, the connection is successful.

Here is what I use to connect to SQL Server:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.DataSource = SQLServerName;
builder.InitialCatalog = SQLDBName;
builder.WorkstationID = SQLServerName;
builder.PacketSize = 4096;
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
builder.ApplicationName = "App";
builder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

using (SqlConnection myDbConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    myDbConn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        myDbConn.Open();

        if (myDbConn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myDbConn.Close();
            return false;
        }

        myDbConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        myDbConn.Close();
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

We have this problem only for a specific user on a specific PC (running Windows 7). I can't figure why moving the program from a network drive to a local drive would change its behavior. I tried adding trust assemblies full control over the shared drive with no results.

Comment: Check the connection string, and remote sql server connection.

Comment: The connection string and remote server are the same with the EXE file on a network share or on a local drive. @ahmed abdelqader

Comment: what is the authentication mode ? is it windows, or SQL Server mixed mode ?

Comment: Using Windows Authentication @ahmed abdelqader

Comment: I think this is the issue, change its Authentication  to be mixed mode.
waiting ur feedback.

Comment: This is not the problem here. We are usingIntegratedSecurity = true here. Also, Windows authentication is working fine when the EXE is local.